# How to implement chat using XMPP in SharePoint?

Tags: development

I need to implement chat using the [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/) protocol in a SharePoint site. Can anyone provide sample code, or recommendations about how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

It will possibly have to be done by developing webparts which uses the XMPP protocol .NET API libraries such as [agxXMPP](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/) or [Jabber-Net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/).